# Warning message after actionSheet buttons are pressed

Tags: ios, warnings, uiimagepickercontroller, uiactionsheet

I am very new to iOS development and have encountered an error that I just can't seem to find a solution for.  I have searched for solutions everywhere, but maybe it is my newness that is preventing me from seeing the problem.

The exact warning that is printed in the log is:

*Attempt to dismiss from view controller <_UIAlertShimPresentingViewController: 0x7aaa4b90> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!*

It occurs right after I touch a button on the actionSheet.

Here is the code:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

} else {

    if (buttonIndex == 0) {

        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;


        [self presentViewController:picker animated:NO completion:NULL];


    }
    else if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];


    }


}
}
```

The implementation of the actionSheet, I have the IBAction connected a toolbar button located an the .xib file.

```
   - (IBAction)addImage:(id)sender {

UIActionSheet *popUpSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                             initWithTitle:nil
                             delegate:self
                             cancelButtonTitle:nil
                             destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                             otherButtonTitles: nil];

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    [popUpSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Camera"];
    [popUpSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Photo Library"];
    [popUpSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Camera Roll"];

    [popUpSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

    popUpSheet.cancelButtonIndex = popUpSheet.numberOfButtons-1;

}   else {

    [popUpSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Photo Library"];
    [popUpSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Camera Roll"];

    [popUpSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

    popUpSheet.cancelButtonIndex = popUpSheet.numberOfButtons-1;

}

[popUpSheet showFromBarButtonItem: self.toolbarItems[0] animated:YES];  }
```

Everything has been delegated correctly from what I can tell:

DetailViewController.m

```
@interface DetailViewController () < UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate >
```

DetailViewController.h

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate>
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated and extremely helpful.

Comment: I might be wrong but I don't see anything wrong with the code, maybe you just presenting this modal view while the current view is also modal view controller, try pushing the views with NavigationControllers rather than presenting each view, or MUST you present them all? I know you need to present the `UIImagePickerController` but you dont always have to present a `UIViewController`.

Comment: Not sure I am following, but then again I am so new at this.  I really appreciate your response emotality, hopefully as I learn more I can understand more about what your talking about.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using storyboards? If NOT, instead of using presentViewController, use the following instead: 

`MyViewController *myController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];` 
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];`

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct. Try using the:

```
actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:
```

method. It's sent to the delegate after the animation ends. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggests..I tried switching over the actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex over to :didDismiss, but I still get the error.  So for now I am just going to keep learning and hopefully over time I'll figure out why that error is appearing.  I really appreciate your response reecon.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the problem.  The compiler was giving me this warning because Apple recently combined UIActionsheet and UIAlert into one controller type called UIAlertController.  Used the new UIAlertController and my problem was solved.

```
- (IBAction)addImage:(id)sender {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;

UIAlertController *popUpSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"Select your Choice" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction *photoLibrary = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Photo Library" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

                            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

                            NSLog(@"Photo Library was touched");
                            [popUpSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
                         }];

UIAlertAction *recentPhotos = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Camera Roll" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

                            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
                            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

                            NSLog(@"Camera Roll was touched");
                            [popUpSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];

                        }];

UIAlertAction *camera = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Camera" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

                            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                            [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

                            NSLog(@"Camera was touched");
                            [popUpSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                        }];

UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

                            [popUpSheet dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                        }];

[popUpSheet addAction:photoLibrary];
[popUpSheet addAction:recentPhotos];

if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
[popUpSheet addAction:camera];
}

[popUpSheet addAction:cancel];

[self presentViewController:popUpSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```